# How to show indeterminate-checkbox?

Tags: materialize

I try to use the indeterminate-checkbox on my web site. The exemple on Materialize work. But when I copy the code on my page, nothing happenning on the checkbox. It's still a normal checkbox unchecked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.css">
<body>
<div id="checkbox" class="section scrollspy">
    <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
                <span>Indeterminate Style</span>
            </label>
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: in your HTML you forgot the form closing tag.

> [:indeterminate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate): The :indeterminate CSS pseudo-class represents any form element whose state is indeterminate.

...

> <input type="checkbox"> elements whose indeterminate property is set to true by JavaScript

In order to set this property you can write in js:

```
document.getElementById('indeterminate-checkbox').indeterminate = true;
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('#indeterminate-checkbox').prop('indeterminate', true);
```

The snippet:

```js
// when document is ready....
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    // set the property
    document.getElementById('indeterminate-checkbox').indeterminate = true;;
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div id="checkbox" class="section scrollspy">
    <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Indeterminate Style</span>
            </label>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```